# Calling a method return output into another method of the same class c++

Tags: c++, class

The code below tries to adds two numbers. I'd like to build a class that does that , for the fun of it.

So, I have method `add` that adds the 2 numbers and returns `result`
I'd like the method `getAdd` to print the return output of the add method.

How do I do this ??

Below is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Addition 
{
    public:
        Addition(double a=0, double b=0);
        double add(double a, double b);
        void getAdd() const;

    private:
        double mA;
        double mB;
};

Addition::Addition(double a, double b) : mA(a), mB(b) {}

double Addition::add(double a, double b)
{
    double result = a + b;

    return result;

}    

void Addition::getAdd() const
{   

    std::cout << "Result is " << //print here the result output of add method << std::endl ;
}          

int main()
{
    Addition sum;
    double num_a;
    double num_b;
    std::cout << "Enter first number to be added\n";
    std::cin >> num_a;
    std::cout << "Enter second number to be added\n";
    std::cin >> num_b;
    sum.add(num_a,num_b);
    sum.getAdd();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can call add with the members mA and mB in getAdd right?

Comment: Also, consider giving better names to your member functions. `getThing` with a `void` return type, that has side effects, violates the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, first you need to declare another variable (it can be `double result;`). Instead of using a local variable called `result`, use the one you've just created.
Your class would be:

```
class Addition 
{
    public:
        Addition(double a=0, double b=0);
        double add(double a, double b);
        void getAdd() const;

    private:
        double mA;
        double mB;
        double result;
};
```

Your add() method would be:

```
double Addition::add(double a, double b)
{
    result = a + b;

    return result;

}
```

And your getAdd() would be:

```
void Addition::getAdd() const {   

    std::cout << "Result is " << result << std::endl ;
}
```

You need this because your getAdd() is a const function, and it cannot call add() directly. =)

Comment: Also `add()` isn't `const`.

Comment: Yes, I've made the changes to fit into it. :)

Comment: hmm,didn't thought of this approach, seems the best for me :) . Thanks!

Comment: Well, if it's what you want, could you please accept it?

Comment: I did accepted it but I have low reputation because I'm new and my acceptance does not appear ... or so I think....

Comment: It has just appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the parameters to getAdd?

```
void Addition::getAdd(double a, double b) const
{
   std::cout << "Result is " << add(a,b);
}
```

Store the result?

```
class Addition 
{
    public:
        Addition(double a=0, double b=0);
        double add(double a, double b);
        void getAdd() const;

    private:
        double mResult;
};

double Addition::add(double a, double b)
{
    mResult = a + b;

    return mResult ;
}    
void Addition::getAdd() const
{
   std::cout << "Result is " << mResult ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define another class member `double last_added;`. Initialise it to something sensible in the constructor. You need to do that in case someone calls `getAdd()` before the first call of `add()`: the behaviour on reading an uninitialised variable is undefined in C++.

Then, in your `add` function, replace the `return` with

`return last_added = result; /*the single = is deliberate*/`

You could refactor `getAdd()`, to return that value:

`return last_added;`

or write the last value to standard output using `std::cout << "Result is " << last_added;`

This is one approach. Another one is to use the `mA` and `mB` members that you've already defined. The function body of `add` becomes

`return mA = a + mB = b;`

That's a real touchstone for your operator precedence knowledge. This has the advantage of your not needing an extra field, since you could write `std::cout << "Result is " << mA + mB;`. But then you're effectively computing the addition twice which is cumbersome.

Do also consider implications of multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

We have two ways of achieving the desired result,

1. Call the function add() from getAdd(), for that you'll have to change the definition of getAdd() to include two parameters.

   void Addition::getAdd(double a, double b) const
   {
       std::cout << "Result is " << add(a,b)<< std::endl ;
   }

(or)

2. store the result in a variable and print it. There are two approaches to it

a.

```
 class Addition 
{
    public:
        Addition(double a=0, double b=0);
        double add(double a, double b);
        void getAdd() const;

    private:
        double mA;
        double mB;
        double add;
};

Addition::Addition(double a, double b) : mA(a), mB(b) {}

double Addition::add(double a, double b)
{
    add = a + b;

    return add;

}    

void Addition::getAdd() const
{   

    std::cout << "Result is " << add() << std::endl ;
}
```

In this case, make sure to call add() first and then getAdd()

```
sum.add(num_a,num_b);
sum.getAdd();
```

Else garbage value will be printed.

Another option is as follows

```
 class Addition 
{
    public:
        Addition(double a=0, double b=0);
        double add(double a, double b);
        void getAdd() const;

    private:
        double mA;
        double mB;
        double add;
};

Addition::Addition(double a, double b) : mA(a), mB(b) {}

double Addition::add(double a, double b)
{
    double result =  a + b;

    return result;

}    

void Addition::getAdd(double a, double b) const
{   
    add = add(a,b)
    std::cout << "Result is " << add << std::endl ;
}
```

and finally call
    getAdd(a,b);

Comment: this answer is also good but the thing is that I want getAdd to be only a getter - read only (That is why i placed the const), just a display function that should not take any parameters but rather just be "servered" with returns from other methods

Comment: I get your point, so the best thing to do is, modify the last answer a bit as shown below

`class Addition 
{
    public:
        Addition(double a=0, double b=0);
        double add(double a, double b);
        void getAdd() const;

    private:
        double mA;
        double mB;
        double add;
        double result;
};

Addition::Addition(double a, double b) : mA(a), mB(b) {}

double Addition::add(double a, double b)
{
    result =  a + b;

    return result;

}  

void Addition::getAdd() const
{   
    std::cout << "Result is " << result << std::endl ;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the meaning of your methods, and your Addtion class.
It's strange.

Maybe your Addtion class is just a class have some methods without any members.
The double add(double a, double b) function is enough for you to get the sum of two double variables.
The void getAdd(double a, double b) function may print some info about sum of two double variables.

```
class Addtion
{
public:
    static double add(double a, double b);
    static void getAdd(double a, double b);
};
```

Or, maybe you can just use namespace. Your really need is just some functions, not a class with members.

```
namespace myaddtion
{
    double add(double a, double b);
    void addinfo(double a, double b);
}
```

Comment: It was just for testing and learning purposes. Of course it would have been much more simpler to do, but I was just looking to test a few things.